# Pseudo Elements and the rotating list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, pseudo-element

I refer to my previous question on JQuery Rotating List. You can view the post here.

[JQuery Rotating List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957478/jquery-rotating-list)

My previous post was to make elements in my table list move horizontally. Applying `td:first-child` and referencing it to my jQuery script as a selector, it works.

But now I'm trying to make my table move vertically. I tried referencing it to tr:first-child but the script just doesn't seem to work.

If I were to change my (tr) to (td), table will be screwed as there are no (tr)'s to seperate the different items in my list. I wonder if there are any way around it.

Or else the other option is to use `<li>` which will require me to change a whole bulk of code.

Anyone who can offer some advice here will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean moving rows of the table vertically, like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/x8dgy/)? Or do you want to move individual table cells?